# Using Print TO PDF file in TChromium (Chromium Embedded)?

Tags: delphi, pdf-generation, chromium-embedded, delphi-xe8

In Delphi XE7/XE8 with TChromium (DCEF3), I need to programmatically print (i.e. save) the current web page to a PDF document file (optionally without user interaction) to a predefined local path. Currently I can do this only indirectly by using a custom PDF printer driver and opening the printer dialog programmatically:

```
procedure TMainForm.btnPrintToPDF(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // open the printer dialog:
  crm.Browser.Host.Print;
end;
```

However, this has two disadvantages:

1. I cannot assume that the end user has a PDF printer driver installed
2. The end user has to select the file path in a file dialog, while the file path should be predefined.

But Chrome has a **built-in** PDF printer driver and print preview which is displayed with the keyboard shortcut CTRL+P. However, when I press CTRL+P in the *guiclient* TChromium demo application then nothing happens, no print preview like in Chrome is displayed.

So how can I call the PDF print preview in TChromium, possibly with a preset output path (without showing the file dialog)?